Создание вариантов отчета для внешнего отчета, когда они не используются
Версия платформы 8.3.21
Столкнулась с такой задачей: в ЗУП 3.1.28 необходимо добавить отчет и сделать так, чтобы он отражался во вкладке "Все кадровые отчеты".
Нашла решение, что для этого необходимо создать вариант отчета и включить его в эту вкладку. Но при подключении внешнего отчета нет вкладки "Варианты отчета" -> "Размещение".
Хранилище вариантов отчета в свойствах заполнено. Отчет написан без использования СКД. Как таковых вариантов у него и нет.
Подскажите, можно ли создать какую-то программную заглушку, чтобы эта вкладка появилась? И куда ее добавить?

Покажите код функции "СведенияОВнешней обработке"
